# R - getting count of maximum-sized sub-group when summarising at prior group_by level

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, summarize

What I am trying to do is along the lines of the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

starwars %>% 
  filter(!is.na(gender)) %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  summarise(total_count = n(), max_species_count_per_gender = max(count(species)))
```

Basically, in addition to trying to get the total count per group separated by `gender` after one `group_by` and reporting that in a summary column, I am also trying to extract the highest subgroup population count of that higher-level group for a given trait (in this case, `species`). Obviously, the above does not work, returning the error message,

```
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "character"
```

So, if I am trying to end up with something along the lines of

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  gender    total_count     max_species_count_per_gender
  <chr>           <int>                            <int>
1 feminine           17                   some_smaller_x
2 masculine          66                   some_smaller_y
```

Is this something I can approach as part of a `summarise` action, or will I need to do something else? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `summarize` twice. The use of `.by...` is an alternative to `group_by` & `ungroup`, either would work.

```r
library(tidyverse)

starwars %>%
  filter(!is.na(gender)) %>%
  summarize(
    sub_count = n(),
    .by = c(species, gender)
  ) %>%
  summarize(
    total_count = sum(sub_count),
    max_species_count = max(sub_count),
    .by = gender
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   gender    total_count max_species_count
#>   <chr>           <int>             <int>
#> 1 masculine          66                26
#> 2 feminine           17                 9
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You could also try `mutate`, `reframe`, and `slice`:

```
starwars %>% 
  filter(!is.na(gender)) %>% 
  mutate(total_count = n(), 
          .by = c(gender)) %>%
  reframe(total_count = total_count,
          max_species_count_per_gender = n(), 
          .by = c(species, gender)) %>%
  slice(1, .by = gender) %>% select(-species)

#   gender    total_count max_species_count_per_gender
#   <chr>           <int>                        <int>
# 1 masculine          66                           26
# 2 feminine           17                            9
```